# Local Angular library in local project

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular library which I publish to a private repository. I then install it in my local project.
The issue is that the library is getting large now and whenever I write new code I have to publish and then run `npm update` to get the changes in my local project.

This is annoying because I have to publish a new version (and increment the version number) of the library no matter how small the change.
I would like it if it were possible to somehow link the library with my project and just see the changes before I have to publish them.

Is this possible?

---

I have tried doing a local `npm install` by running:

```
npm install ..\situ-angular-components\dist\situ-angular-components\
```

but this shows an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use your library from sources rather than from the artifact. Most of open source libraries use this pattern.

Look for example on this one: [date-time-picker](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker)

What might be interesting for you is that there is an app module which imports the library like this:

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from '../../projects/picker/src/public_api';
```

So it basically points to the sources of the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try @Marcin kunert answer or you can just do

```
npm install ../srcofyoulibraryproject
```

and it will take all the changes you doing without changing to import statement

Comment: Yeah, this works better and I can do a `ng build example-project --watch` on the library so it's always up to date

Comment: yes exactly, I forget to mention this too, good luck

Comment: actually, it doesn't work. When I try to install it, it complains that it can't write to the node_modules folder

Comment: do you mean problems to write in the folder (node_modules)?